# How to convert a column form object to float?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv whose columns include the results of some mathematic calculations. When I read the csv, the datatype of these columns is object. The content of the columns are numbers like this "9,180693865" (or 0)

Now I tried the following to change the datatype:

```
df["column"].astype('float64')

df["column"] = Erzeugung.solar_prediction.astype("float64")

pd.to_numeric(df["column"])
```

The error message Looks like this:
ValueError: Unable to parse string "9,180693865" at position 27

Is there something else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `,` by a `.` using `str.replace` to fix this:

```
df["column"] = Erzeugung.solar_prediction.str.replace(',', '.').astype("float64")
```

Comment: That worked just fine, thank you!